# How can a Dockerfile depend on a running container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, continuous-integration

I have a project with a web application with unit tests and firebase emulators containerized separately. I would like to include the unit tests in the web app's Dockerfile, however they depend on the emulators to be running.

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788472/how-can-one-make-a-docker-compose-service-build-depend-on-another-service) that has been answered but I do not think this answer is suitable. I couldn't find anything in the docker compose documentation that mentions `depends_on` has anything to do with orchestrating build and run order, to my knowledge it is only suitable for controlling startup and shutdown order.

Here are the solutions I can come up with:

1. **Wait for emulators to be live in the application's Dockerfile.** If compose runs images as soon as they are built (with respect to service dependencies), then I can wait for the emulators to be available on host ports in the Dockerfile. The only caveat is that I'm implementing health checks to signal to docker when the emulators are running, so I would have to duplicate that logic in the Dockerfile. (If I can wait for the emulators service to be healthy instead, this might be the best solution available)
2. **Package emulators and the application in the same container.** This actually has some quality of life improvements because the web container now has access to the firebase cli for better control over emulators which otherwise would have required the emulators container to host a shell server. However, this does not scale well if multiple containers depend on firebase emulators, especially with end to end tests.
3. **Package emulators in the testing build stage of the application.** This way emulators can be shared across multiple containers but this approach has a lot of duplication, can get confusing and unnecessarily increases overhead which isn't great for CI.
4. **Create a more complicated build script than compose.**

I'm going to explore the first solution, but is there a solution native to docker for something like this? Does `depends_on` have some behavior to aid in the build phase that isn't explicitly stated?

**EDIT:**
I thought of another solution, if I can just specify the build order for compose I can build the emulators image first then use it as the base image for the test build stage. That way there is not code duplication and the build does not depend on the host environment.

Comment: Can you run these functional tests in your host build environment, before you start building an image?  A Dockerfile can't start or call out to other containers at all, and the results of the tests presumably don't need to be persisted in the image.

Comment: This is part of a CI workflow where the unit tests will cause the build to fail if they do not succeed. With multi-stage builds they do not affect the footprint of the final image.

Comment: Right, so there's a spot like a `Jenkinsfile` or some other setup for your CI system where you can run these tests first.

Comment: That was my plan previously with github actions, but I felt it might make more sense to put them in the image itself. It would be easier to manage and I get the advantage of layer caching.

Comment: Now that I think about it that is probably a more proper solution and what I've been trying is counter-productive towards containerized applications.

I think I have narrowed it down to three solutions. I can use the emulators image as the base for the testing build stage (which would require me to organize build order which docker doesn't seem to support), I can use a mocking library in place of emulators, and I can just exclude the tests from the image and handle setting up the environment separately in CI.